# How to "Import Queries" in the Web Interface of ArangoDB?

Tags: import, format, arangodb

"Export Queries" does not work in the [Query tab of the Web Interface](http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html#queries), so I tried to manually create json with the query and import it, but the following definition is not clear:

```
Format: 
JSON documents embedded into a list:

[{
    "name": "Query Name",
    "value": "Query Definition",
    "parameter": "Query Bind Parameter as Object"
}]
```

What escaping should have the `value`, whether `parameter` is mandatory and what is the format in case multiple bind parameters are defined.

I was not able to import the following script:

```
[{
    name: "Create Random Complex Users (num, outpUsers)",
    value: '// Create specified number of users in the users Vertex collection
FOR i IN 1..@usersNum
  INSERT {
    id: 100000 + i,
    age: 18 + FLOOR(RAND() * 50),  // RAND generate float E {0, 1]
    name: CONCAT('user', TO_STRING(i)),
  } IN @@users'
}
]
```

What is wrong and how should it be fixed?

**NOTE:**
ArangoDB version: `arangosh (ArangoDB 3.0.10 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014)`

Using the JSON fixed by @mpv1989 the following error appears in the Web Inetface: `Query error: queries could not be imported`.
And the following message is in the log using DB named `test` under the root user:

```
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR Service "/_admin/aardvark" encountered error 500 while handling POST http://localhost:8529/_db/test/_admin/aardvark/query/upload/root
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR ArangoError: users can only be used in _system database
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at getStorage (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/users.js:93:17)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at Object.exports.document (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/users.js:291:17)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at Route._handler (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP/aardvark.js:153:18)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at next (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/foxx/router/tree.js:386:15)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at /usr/share/arangodb3/js/node/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9378:25
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at Middleware.authRouter.use (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP/aardvark.js:78:3)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at next (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/foxx/router/tree.js:388:15)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at next (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/foxx/router/tree.js:384:7)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at next (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/foxx/router/tree.js:384:7)
2016-10-26T12:31:28Z [31690] ERROR     at next (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/server/modules/@arangodb/foxx/router/tree.js:384:7)
```

However, the fixed JSON can be SUCCESSFULLY imported to the _SYSTEM database! Thank you @mpv1989.
It seems, persistence and import of the Queries snippets works only for the _SYSTEM DB...

Comment: which ArangoDB version do you use?

Comment: The latest release for Ubuntu from their site: "ArangoDB 3.0.10 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error message do you get when exporting/importing?

For your workaround, I exported your query from the Web Interface. Here is the result:

```
[{
    "name": "Create Random Complex Users (num, outpUsers)",
    "value": "// Create specified number of users in the users Vertex collection\nFOR i IN 1..@usersNum\n  INSERT {\n    id: 100000 + i,\n    age: 18 + FLOOR(RAND() * 50),  // RAND generate float E {0, 1]\n    name: CONCAT('user', TO_STRING(i))\n  } IN @@users",
    "parameter": {
        "usersNum": 100,
        "@users": "users"
    }
}]
```

The field `parameter` is a Json Object. If you do not have any bind parameter just write an empty object `"parameter": {}`.

Comment: Thank you @mpv1989, this JSON is exportable! Thought, unfortunately  it could be done only for the _SYSTEM database (see the error log above)...